# angular.injector(['moduleName']).get('name') works for Factory and not for Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-controller, angularjs-injector

I am using require.js to modularize the code and getting following error:

```js
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $filterProvider <- $filter <- srvcConverter
```

here is the Service module:

```
define('services/converter', ['angular'], function(angular) {

    var moduleName = 'mdlConverter',

     angular.module(moduleName, []).service('srvcConverter', ['$filter', function($filter) {
        this.formatDateTime = function(value) {
            if (value) {
                return $filter('date')(new Date(value), 'medium');
            }
        };
    }]);
    return moduleName;
});
```

and here is the Factory Module:

```
define('factories/utils', ['angular', 'factories/validator'], function(angular, fcValidator) {

    var moduleName = 'mdlUtils';

    angular.module(moduleName, [fcValidator]).factory("fctrUtils", ['fctrValidator', function(fctrValidator) {

        return {
            'capitalize' : function(str) {
                return typeof str === 'string' && str.length ? (str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)) : str;
            }
        };
    }]);
    return moduleName;
});
```

and below one is the caller module:

```
 define(['app', 'services/converter', 'factories/utils'], function(app, converterService, utils) {

    var utils = angular.injector([utils]).get('fctrUtils'); // This works fine.
    var converter = angular.injector([converterService]).get('srvcConverter'); // This throws mentioned error

    function TableController($scope) {
        $scope.draw = function() {}
    }
    app.register.controller('TableController', TableController);

    return TableController;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

'$filter' dependency was causing the issue.

Just adding the `'ng'` as module dependency resolved the issue.

```
angular.module(moduleName, ['ng']).service('srvcConverter', ['$filter', function($filter) {

}]);
```